# How can I handle this AJAX(?) bug?

Tags: javascript

So I have a bug,everytime i try to click on an element(Generated by an autocomplete function I made using jquery) I can access it only if i click in middle,however,if i use arrows & enter it works everytime . Any ideeas? My code is. Maybe i just don't see it but i am looking at it for a few hours

```
{literal}

$(document).ready(function() {

    function autocomplete(inp) {
      var currentFocus;
      var arr =[];
      inp.on("input", function(e) {
          var a, b, i, val = this.value;
          closeAllLists();
          if (!val) { return false;}
          currentFocus = -1;    
          a = document.createElement("DIV");
          a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
          a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
          this.parentNode.append(a);
          $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"//",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {user_id: __st.a, keyword: val},
            success: function(products) {
                if(products.length){
                    products.forEach(function (product, index) {
                        b = document.createElement("div");
                        var div_class = "bundle_autocomplete_item_"+index;
                        b.setAttribute("class", div_class);
                        b.innerHTML = '<span style="float: left; display: block; width: 20%;"><img src="' + product.image_url + '" alt="productImageSrc"></span><span class="autocomplete-title">' + product.title + '</span>';
                        $(b).on("click", function(e) {
                            closeAllLists();
                            window.location.href = 'https://'+Shopify.shop+'/products/'+product.handle;
                        });
                        a.appendChild(b);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
      });

      inp.on("keydown", function(e) {
          var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
          if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
          if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            currentFocus++;
            addActive(x);
          } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
            currentFocus--;
            addActive(x);
          } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (currentFocus > -1) {
              if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
            }
          }
      });

        function addActive(x) {
            if (!x) return false;
            removeActive(x);
            if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
            if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
            x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
      }

        function removeActive(x) {
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
            }
        }

        function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
                    x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var searchForms = $('form[action="/search"]').each(function() {
        $('input[name="q"]').each(function() {
            $(this).attr("autocomplete" , "off");
            autocomplete($(this));
        });
    });
$('head').append('<style> .autocomplete {position: relative;display: inline-block;border:10px solid red;} .autocomplete-items {position: absolute;border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;border-bottom: none;border-top: none;z-index: 99;top: 100%;left:0;right: 0;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;} .autocomplete-items div {padding: 7px ;cursor: pointer;background-color: #fff; border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden;}} .autocomplete-items div:hover {background-color: #e9e9e9;}.autocomplete-active {background-color: DodgerBlue !important; color: #ffffff;} .autocomplete-title{font-size:13px; margin-left:3px;</style>');});

{/literal}
```

I removed the url from the ajax call for personal reasons

Comment: It sounds to me like your element isn't properly clickable...

Comment: Something like that but I can't find a fix to it because it looks okay

Comment: Doesn't seem like AJAX. As @NiettheDarkAbsol says, the element is probably not clickable. It might be smaller than what's on the page or something.

Comment: Aight thanks guys imma try to look a lil bit more

Comment: make a minimal viable example using jsbin or jsfiddle

Comment: the problem may be that you have float element and on parent div not so it contain only title. You can check developer tools if div is smaller then the image. But you have `overflow: hidden` so this shouldn't happen.